# Till what age are frog feet a normal issue?

Tags: newborn

My twin boys are 10 weeks old. One of them has his legs as the frog legs position. Till what age must I consider this a normal issue?  or is it abnormal already? I thought it was normal that I hadn't asked his ped yet.

Comment: I don't think this is asking for medical advice.  While I personally don't tend to love these kinds of questions, [this meta question](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/670/are-questions-about-generic-medical-fundamental-medical-information-on-topic)'s highest voted answer confirms this kind of question is fine.

Comment: Could you possibly find a picture or describe what *frog legs position* means to you? Also, were they early, and if so, at what week's gestation were they born?

Comment: Has a doctor checked them for developmental dysplasia of the hip (DDH) aka 'clicky hip'? http://www.nct.org.uk/parenting/hip-dysplasia-babies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the International Hip Dysplasia Institute](http://hipdysplasia.org/developmental-dysplasia-of-the-hip/prevention/baby-carriers-seats-and-other-equipment/), it can take "several months", and [Babycenter.com](http://www.babycenter.com/0_your-newborns-development_1477143.bc#articlesection1) says it can take "6 months" for the legs to straighten out. While I hardly consider those sites as clear experts on this issue (the articles weren't written to specifically address your question), they do seem to indicate that it is normal for a 10 week old baby to not keep his legs straight.

That being said, one cannot rule out the possibility of a medical condition. According to [the American Academy of Orthopedic Surgeons](http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=a00347), if your baby has developmental dislocation of the hip, it is best for him to be treated early. I'd recommend asking your pediatrician if you are worried.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE -- I converted your third link for you :) Thanks for the Answer!

Comment: I expanded "this"s into the name of the sites - it is better to make it more clear who you're citing than to require readers to hover on the link to find out.

Comment: After all, it took nearly 6 months for him to straighten his legs. now he is 2 yrs old, and he walks, crawls, jumps, and climbs very well... thnx all

Comment: Thank you for following up. I'm thrilled to hear the good news!